# Can I connect to localhost on SSMS without being a system admin?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

How to setup and use temporary local db without admin privilege on the system.

Comment: Did you try windows authentication ?
On SSMS's dialog window for configuring connection properties, under "Authentication" choose "Windows Authentication" from dropdown. In that case - as far as I know - you should not worry about privileges.

Comment: Management Studio itself is just a client tool. You also need an instance of SQL Server itself to connect to. Whether you can connect or not to any particular instance depends on what options were selected during installation and any changes to its security configuration since. None of those (aside from the installation itself) care all that much about the local *windows* administrators.

Comment: "system admin" - you mean a Windows system admin or a SQL Server system admin? These are different things.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need admin privileges. If you just want a test DB to play around with:

Download a free SQL server instance from this link choose Express or Developer and basic options. Save the sql server somewhere on your local machine.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Once it's downloaded you'll need to open  SQL Server Management Studio. In the Object Explorer click on the left select 'connect' then 'new database engine'. In the window that pops up select 'Server Name' and 'browse for more'. You should find the local DB that you just downloaded and saved. You can then select that and connect to it. That'll give you a new instance of SQL server to play around with.

If you already have a SQL server set up, follow the last steps and just enter it in the server name and connect. You shouldn't need admin privileges.